# Smallest Common Multiple [Javascript Challenge]

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question:** Find the smallest common multiple of the provided parameters that can be evenly divided by both, as well as by all sequential numbers in the range between these parameters.

The range will be an array of two numbers that will not necessarily be in numerical order.

For example, if given 1 and 3, find the smallest common multiple of both 1 and 3 that is also evenly divisible by all numbers between 1 and 3, i.e. divisible by 1, 2 and 3. The answer here would be 6.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max=Math.max(...arr);
  var min=Math.min(...arr);
  var flag = 0;
  var i = min;
    while(true)
    {for(var j=min;j<=max;j++)
        {if(i%j!=0)
          {flag=1;
          break;}
        }
      if(flag==0)
        {flag=5;
        break;
        }
      i++;
    }
console.log(i);
}

smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

For somereason my solution seems to go crazy and go into infinite looping. Although if I initialize var i to 60 (which is the desired output for this specific case i.e.[1,5]) the solution seems to be fine. Any fixes or guesses?

Comment: use the debugger

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging. But it all just doesn't seem to work. I'm relatively new to all of this. Hence it is difficult for me to debug. StackOverflow would know. ._.

Comment: The moment you set your flag to a value different than 0, your loop will become infinite. You only stop your while loop when flag = 0.

Comment: @KevinAmorim Oh yes. I do see that now. Any suggestion on where I can re-initialize flag to 0 for this to work?

Comment: @AdilAhmed debugging is a critical skill in programming. It's something you should spend some time learning now

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your quick responses. After seeing @KevinAmorim's comment, I did realize that I needed to re-initialize var flag=0 again, if all the elements of the j'th loop were checked and none of them resulted in the break. So I made some tweaks to the code, and checked if(j==max){flag=0;} as the last line of the j'th loop.

Comment: Nice! I'm glad you did manage to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kevin has given a pretty good explanation of why it's not working. Your loop will only stop if `flag` is `0`. But once it has been set to `1`, you never reset it to `0`.

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(...arr);
  var min = Math.min(...arr);
  var flag = 0;
  var i = min;
  while (true) {
    for (var j = min; j <= max; j++) {
      if (i % j != 0) {
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
      return i; // Return that common value
    }
    flag = 0; // Reset the flag
    i++;
  }
}

console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
```

And here is an alternative way:

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  const min = Math.min(...arr),
        max = Math.max(...arr),
        range = createRange(min, max);
        
  let current = max;

  while (true) {
    const isFullyDivisible = range.every(n => current % n === 0);
    if (isFullyDivisible) {
      return current;
    }
    current++;
  }
}

function createRange(min, max) {
  return new Array(max - min + 1).fill(null).map((_, i) => min + i);
}

console.log(smallestCommons([1, 3]));  // 6
console.log(smallestCommons([5, 1]));  // 60
console.log(smallestCommons([1, 10])); // 2520
```

Comment: Aye man. This works perfectly. It did take me sometime to understand your code, but now that I do, I can safely say that my doubt is cleared. Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did figure out the solution, thanks to the two programming geeks in the main comments sections.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max=Math.max(...arr);
  var min=Math.min(...arr);
  var flag = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var i = 1;
    while(1){
      for(var j=min;j<=max;j++)
      {if(i%j!=0)
        {flag=1;
        break;}
      if(j==max){
        flag=0;
      }
      }
      if(flag==0){
        break;
      }
      i++;
 }
console.log(i);
}


smallestCommons([10,2]);
```